# Undefined control sequence error, I don't understand which part is the error

Tags: errors, overleaf

Undefined control sequence error, I'm confused on which part is the error in my text, an error appears undefined control sequence on line 149. which contains the following text `\section{Introduction}\label{sec1}` . but in detail log shows following error

```
\auaddress ...v {Informatics Engineering}, \ordiv 
                                                  {Faculty of Computer Scien...
l.149 \section
              {Introduction}\label{sec1}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

LaTeX Font Info:    Calculating math sizes for size <10.03749> on input line 149.
```

I've searched for `\auaddress` but I can't find \auaddress in my text, this is the text in the part that is the `\auaddress` connection from the error

```
\affil[1]{\orgdiv{Informatics Engineering}, \ordiv{Faculty of Computer Science}, \orgname{Brawijaya University}, \country{Indonesia}}
```

text does anyone know what the problem is? Thank You

[image: line 149 which is an error]

[image]

Comment: The undefined command could a internal command used by a package (.sty) , the document class file (.cls) or a external file (.tex). Without a MWE is impossible to know.
Lighten the contents removing parts irrelevant for this error, and the same with the preamble, and post the entire document  (i.e., a few lines of code, but   compilable "as is").

Comment: Hello. There's no way to debug this without a complete MWE. However, in the line above beginning with `\affil` I see you use both `\orgdiv` and `\ordiv` and the latter matches the undefined control sequence in the error message. That may be the problem.

Comment: In the error message, the undefined control sequence is the last item in the first line after the error message, in this case `\ordiv`, which looks like a typo you made.